# How to use `XML` and `Web Service Data Sources` as a source for `Reporting Services`?

Tags: web-services, reporting-services

How to use `XML` and `Web Service Data Sources` as a source for `Reporting Services`?

Comment: *its very urgent* : then maybe you should have posted your question some days ago... By the way, I think you should elaborate a bit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an idea of how it works, [here is a very simple example](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/using-web-service-as-a-data-source-in-sql-server-reporting-services/).

And here is the official version: [Reporting Services: Using XML and Web Service Data Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964129%28SQL.90%29.aspx). If you scroll down to the Examples section, you can step through the process.

Comment: Thank you for responce,
I tried those steps but i stuckup at connection string.
from where i get .asmx connection string.
If you can give your mail id i will send my SOAp query.

Comment: Let's keep out discussion public here, so that others will benefit from the information. In that MSDN article, in step 5 of the first example, it gives the syntax for the connection string which is http://<Server Name>/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx. You just need to substitute your server name and the .asmx page name.